# Should Apache own /var/www/domain.com directory in WordPress?

Tags: permissions

In a lot of tutorials on WordPress installation I see apache:apache user:group given to the files in WordPress and the domain directory.

Should it be Apache or some non-root user ?

Comment: You should ask the people that wrote those tutorials.